# Class "Botble\Base\Supports\ServiceProvider" not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am installing **composer require botble/api**  This package in my laravel project.
While installing I am facing this issues.

> In ApiServiceProvider.php line 16:
> Class "Botble\Base\Supports\ServiceProvider" not found**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This Is one more error.

Comment: So what's inside `ApiServiceProvider.php` then? Is this class being used before composer installs and autoloads it?

Comment: I don't have that file.

Comment: Please edit your question and post text not images.

Comment: If you face any problem with the pure installation of any package, please open a bug report in their issue tracker

Comment: I have faced the same issue and fixed it by removing bootstrap/cache/  files and vendor folder, then running the composer install command.

Answer (score 3):

That package looks like it is part of a paid CMS product by `botble`. It looks like it depends on the CMS being installed first, and then you can add the api package in later, if you want.

The service provider in that package is extending the `Botble\Base\Supports\ServiceProvider` class, which I am assuming is part of the base CMS product. Since the base CMS is not installed (or not installed properly), the class doesn't exist, so that is why you're getting that error.

The CMS not being installed properly would be why you're also getting the error about the "platform/packages" path not existing.

I assume you will need to purchase the base CMS and follow their video tutorial in the docs to install it properly. Once installed properly, you should be able to add the api package to it.